# How to achieve Wonderful Boy for Nun and the Devil?

Tags: half-minute-hero

Apparently you need to strike a time of less than 30 seconds to get Wonderful Hero on this level. However, according to the leaderboards only 29 people ever have done so on the Windows port at the time of the post and certainly it does look hard!

How can I achieve this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strike such an extraordinaire performance you just have to make a pact with the devil.

1. From the start dash to the town right next to you, use the herb.
2. Move towards the southern village - dash through each and every battle but do not dash during your travel.
3. Enter the village, replenish your health.
4. Dash to the tower to your east and enter it.
5. Dash through every floor, making sure to consume the herb when necessary.
6. Dash back to the village, talk to the <s>fair villager</s> terrible terrible demon thing.
7. Once you leave the village move one step to the left* then dash up to the intersection to acquire your powers.
8. Dash to the castle and through the boss fight.

*This is to make sure you don't lose time trying to dash through rock. I've had to throw away a couple runs for this. :/

If you still can't make it in 30 seconds, check your equipment - especially the weight statistic. The Gold Scudetto, for example, has the best defense at this point (+2) but carries a +15 to weight. Prefer the Merc Shield that trades 1 defense (enough to make it through) with 14 weight and throws 1 more evasion on top of it.